# Check if there is a value defined in the firebase database - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, discord.js

I'm developing a bot for discord, and I'm using the firebase database. In the code below, I want to check if the value `mstatus` is set to `"CASADO"`, but if this value does not exist yet, execute another command.

```js
database.ref(`Servidores/${message.guild.id}/Users/${message.author.id}/Casamento`).once('value').then(async function(db) {
        
        if (db.val().mstatus === 'CASADO') {
            const embederro = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(process.env.COLOR)
            .setDescription(`**<a:9999:847961716527595520> **Você já está casado. Use \`${process.env.PREFIX}divorciar\` para poder divorciar.`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(moment(message.createdAt).format('D/MM/YYYY'))
            .setAuthor(`Awake Bot`,bot.user.displayAvatarURL())

            message.channel.send(embederro)

            return;
        } else {
            console.log('OK');
        }
    })
```

The code above returns this error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'mstatus' of null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the `key` of the location of this `DataSnapshot` is `null`:

```js
database
  .ref(`Servidores/${message.guild.id}/Users/${message.author.id}/Casamento`)
  .once('value')
  .then(async function (snapshot) {
    const key = snapshot.key;

    if (key === null)
      return console.log(`The value doesn't exist yet`);

    const val = snapshot.val();

    if (val === null)
      return console.log(`The value is null`);

    if (val.mstatus === 'CASADO') {
      const embederro = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(process.env.COLOR)
        .setDescription(
          `**<a:9999:847961716527595520> **Você já está casado. Use \`${process.env.PREFIX}divorciar\` para poder divorciar.`,
        )
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(moment(message.createdAt).format('D/MM/YYYY'))
        .setAuthor(`Awake Bot`, bot.user.displayAvatarURL());

      return message.channel.send(embederro);
    }

    console.log(`The value exists but the mstatus is ${val.mstatus}`);
  });
```

Comment: Mine continued to give the error "Cannot read property 'mstatus' of null". Since the "mstatus" value is not defined in the database when a user has just entered the server. Can you help me with that?

Comment: You could also check if the `val` is null. I've just updated my answer. Does it work as expected?

Comment: It's great to hear that. You're welcome :)

Comment: Key is a non-null value and for the code above will always equal `"Casamento"` so there is no need to null test it (even if the data doesn't exist). While you can test `snapshot.val() == null`, it is more correct to test `snapshot.exists()` instead.